# Winsorization of outliers by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I ran into a strange problem when trying to winsorize outliers by a group.
let's say we have a data set like this, and we would like to winsorize both col1 and col2 at whatever threshold we deem reasonable.

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(1:200, 101:300),
  col2 = c(1:199, NA, 101:110,NA, 112:300),
  year = c(rep(2005,200), rep(2006,200))
)
```

My first try is:

```
df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate_at(.funs = list(wins = robustHD::winsorize), .vars = vars(col1, col2)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

However, nothing is changed.
Then I try antoher function (DescTools::Winsorize),

```
df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate_at(.funs = list(wins = Winsorize), .vars = vars(col1, col2), probs = c(0.05, 0.95), na.rm=TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()
```

And it works.
I try the `TIDYVERSE (dplyr)` from @Parfait 's answer on a sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494337/95-winsorization-by-groups-over-multiple-variables), and it seems that `robustHD::winsorize` does works, although no clue why the value of group `1` of `test2` is all NaN.
Anyone knows why would this happen?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with `dplyr` specifically. The two functions just seem to have different definitions of "winsorizing". Compare the output of `robustHD::winsorize(df$col1)` and `DescTools::Winsorize(df$col1)`. Read the docs to see which more closely matches what you want to happen with your data

Comment: Even though, I still do not understand why the `robustHD::winsorize` method changed the data in the link I post, but have not changed my sample.